# CPU speed is way less than the supposed minimum--is this a sign of hardware failure?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 on an old Dell laptop, Intel Core 2 Duo CPU and noticed that the CPU is being all used up by ordinary tasks (e.g. web browsing) that have not typically been a problem. Running 
    lscpu | grep 'MHz' | awk '{print }'
gives
    CPU MHz:              660.0000 // This number fluctuates a little
    CPU max MHz:         2200.0000
    CPU min MHz:         1200.0000
The fact that the current CPU speed is way less than the advertised min seems a little concerning to me, although I don't know much about CPUs. The results are the same even when I run "stress -c 2" Is this a sign that the CPU is dying, or am I off track?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually have a performance problem? It might just be a battery saving measure or something. It might even be a (possibly bad) driver update.

Comment: I've flagged to move this question to https://superuser.com

Comment: @Luaan yes, the performance is bad--everything is slow, and Firefox freezes all the time. Interestingly, after a few days this fixed itself, although I have no idea how. Everything was up-to-date-throughout....

Answer (score 0):

there could be multiple problems:

- There could be some background tasks, which are always running in your computer. If 
  you've had your pc for a lot of time, you might have installed and uninstalled many 
  programs/applications. Some don't complitely uninstall or leave some .exe file that 
  works in your background, and this can obviously use some of your's cpu power.
- Or, it is likely to be the heat. If the cpu temperature is too high, the computer will 
  have to decrease cpu's power to stop it from overheating. To help your computer from 
  overheating you should either clean (in the inside) the parts where the air circulates, 
  close to the fans, or use some gadgets like [this](https://www.amazon.it/Ewent-EW1256-Supporto-Raffreddamento-Silenziosa/dp/B01B34928M/ref=sr_1_12?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2TG7Y6PDY3TQ9&keywords=laptop+cooler&qid=1565008722&s=gateway&sprefix=laptop+%2Caps%2C314&sr=8-12).

Hope this helped you! :)

Comment: Although I agree on second bullet, the `.exe` reference in first one when OP is using Ubuntu is quite controversial. Also, background tasks should not influence the reported CPU speed (but only its load).

Comment: Yes, I would try the second option. You can install a simple program to check your cpu's temperature to see if that is the problem, and if it is, possibly fix it in the ways i explained.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Using tools like top/iotop/atop, etc. I can see that the load and CPU speed were uncorrelated. As for the heat, this was also a thought of mine since there I have had this issue before, but the "sensors" utility reports no overheating (and my hand agrees). As I commented above just now too, the problem ended up going away after a week or so, which is pretty confusing to me...

Comment: @ZachBoyd Perfect, that's good! If you can set this question as "answered" by clicking the ✓ button (under the up, and down arrows), if your problem is solved! Thank you! :)